# Are solar cells designed to be isotropic to polarization?

Tags: polarization, solar-cells

The typical performance charts I see report efficiency ([IPCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_cell_efficiency#Quantum_efficiency)) as a function of wavelength. Since the light coming from the sun has [random polarization](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/218110/what-is-the-exact-meaning-distribution-of-unpolarized-light), wouldn't a solar cell with anisotropic polarization efficiency be less efficient than an isotropic cell? Why absorption spectra/conversion efficiency for polarized light is not reported as well, to demonstrate how well the cell manages random polarization?

For [example](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/b926051j),

[image]

Comment: What factors would lead to a large assymetry in polarization response?

Comment: @JonCuster, [transition dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_dipole_moment); added figure.

Comment: Fair enough - but molecules are a different ball game from crystals. The largest effect in, say, a crystalline Si solar cell would be the reflectivity difference if you had it at near-glancing angle to the sun.